# MPI_Alltoallv send empty arrays to processors?

Tags: c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I need to send data from all processors to all processors.
So from first proc:

```
P1: 10; P2: 27,6 ; P3: 21
```

from second proc:

```
P1: 8,22; P2: nothing; P3: nothing;
```

from third proc:

```
P1: 18; P2: 54; P3: nothing.
```

How I should organize `MPI_Alltoallv` function to send this values?

Comment: Are the numbers you show the data you wish to send, or the amount of data you wish to send? If the latter, what is meant by e.g. `27,6`?

Comment: it's a data, array values

Comment: Sparse exchange probably runs faster with well-written send-recv than alltoallv on most networks. Blue Gene would be the obvious exception.